# Pull request from git to project

Tags: android, git, github

How can I get the github request file by pull method and add it into my project? I already implemented the library in the gradle. I want to add this fill using pull request for only an hourly selection of the time pop up:

https://github.com/wdullaer/MaterialDateTimePicker/pull/211

```
git clone git@github.com:jdegroot/MaterialDateTimePicker.git
git checkout feature_hour_only
```

Build the library with Gradle and move the aar your project